# Convert RDD[String] to RDD[Row] to Dataframe Spark Scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am reading in a file that has many spaces and need to filter out the space. Afterwards we need to convert it to a dataframe. Example input below.

```
2017123 ¦     ¦10¦running¦00000¦111¦-EXAMPLE
```

My solution to this was the following function which parses out all spaces and trims the file.

```
def truncateRDD(fileName : String): RDD[String] = {
    val example = sc.textFile(fileName)
    example.map(lines => lines.replaceAll("""[\t\p{Zs}]+""", ""))
}
```

However, I am not sure how to get it into a dataframe. `sc.textFile` returns a `RDD[String]`. I tried the case class way but the issue is we have 800 field schema, case class cannot go beyond 22.

I was thinking of somehow converting RDD[String] to RDD[Row] so I can use the `createDataFrame` function.

```
val DF = spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)
```

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Answer (score 8):

First split/parse your strings into the fields.

`rdd.map( line => parse(line))` where parse is some parsing function.  It could be as simple as split but you may want something more robust.  This will get you an `RDD[Array[String]]` or similar.

You can then convert to an `RDD[Row]` with `rdd.map(a => Row.fromSeq(a))`

From there you can convert to DataFrame wising `sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)` where rdd is your `RDD[Row]` and schema is your schema StructType.

Comment: I have an array of nested JSON to parse, how can I convert it into data frame?

Answer (score 0):

In your case simple way :

> ```
> val RowOfRDD = truncateRDD("yourfilename").map(r => Row.fromSeq(r))
> ```

#### How to solve `productarity` issue if you are using scala 2.10 ?

> However, I am not sure how to get it into a dataframe. `sc.textFile`
>   returns a RDD[String]. I tried the case class way but the issue is we
>   have 800 field schema, case class cannot go beyond 22.

Yes, There are some limitations like `productarity`  but we can overcome... 
you can do like below example for < versions 2.11 :

prepare a case class which `extends Product` and overrides methods.

like...

- `productArity():Int:` This returns the size of the attributes. In our case, it's 33. So, our implementation looks like this:
- `productElement(n:Int):Any:` Given an index, this returns the attribute. As protection, we also have a default case, which throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` exception:
- `canEqual (that:Any):Boolean`: This is the last of the three functions, and it serves as a boundary condition when an equality check is being done against class:

---

- Example implementation you can refer [this Student case class which has 33 fields in it](https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/big-data-and-business-intelligence/9781784396749/3/ch03lvl1sec22/loading-more-than-22-features-into-classes)
- Example [student dataset description here](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Student+Performance)

Comment: scala 2.11 on wards arity issue is not there. below versions of scala above approach is applicable